# Silly odometry question

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I wanted to ask - if I publish a twist topic, are the velocities interpreted as intrinsic or extrinsic (by the navigation stack, for example).

I'll elaborate: Lets say i start at zero position with my robot, and turn 45 degrees right. Now I drive it 1 [m/s] forward (just for the sake of calculations). Should I be publishing the intrinsic ("robot coordinates") velocities, meaning Vx=1 and Vy=0, or should I be publishing the extrinsic ("world coordinates") velocities, meaning Vx=Vy=1/sqrt(2) ?
I would go for the robot coordinates (saving Vy for holonomic robots), but had to ask for sure....

Many thanks,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271217/silly-odometry-question/) by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You get to specify what you mean within the message itself so that there is no ambiguity. Check out [ROS REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), where some common coordinate frames and their meanings are discussed. What you are calling "robot coordinates" is called `base_link`, and "world coordinates" is called `odom`. Note that there are multiple extrinsic frames, with `map` and `utm` being the other common extrinsic frames in addition to `odom`.

The way that you specify which coordinate frame you are using is by setting the `Header/frame_id` field. It is then up to the nodes subscribing to your messages to correctly interpret the data. Very often, [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) is used to transform data into the appropriate frame for the specific receiving node. If there is no `Header/frame_id` field (as is the case for the basic `Twist` message) then I have seen most subscribing nodes assume that the `Twist` data is in the `base_link` frame. If possible, it is nicer to use the `TwistStamped` or `TwistWithCovarianceStamped` variants of the message type for this reason.

For your specific question, I have mostly seen robot velocity measurements (from GPS, wheel encoders, Kalman filters, etc.) be published and interpreted as being in the `base_link` (or intrinsic, "robot coordinates") frame.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2017-09-21**:
Thank you very much, I forgot to specifically mention the sole existence of "odom" and "base_link" frames.
This completely answered my question.